# What are the differences between the purposes of generator functions and asynchronous generator functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-3.6, coroutine

In Python, asynchronous generator functions are coroutines, and generator functions are also coroutines.

What are the differences between the purposes of generator functions and asynchronous generator functions?

Thanks.

Comment: CV-voter, if the question was too broad an answer of the length that I provided wouldn't be possible. Don't vote indiscriminately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The purpose of [PEP 525 -- Asynchronous Generators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/) is pretty much similar to [PEP 255 -- Simple Generators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/)  which introduced generators. It is mainly intented to make things *easier* to implement, only in a different domain (asynchronous one). From PEP 525:

> Essentially, the goals and rationale for PEP 255, applied to the asynchronous execution case, hold true for this proposal as well.

In short, it makes writing objects that support the [asynchronous iteration protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#asynchronous-iterators) easy. As *generators* did for the *iterator protocol*.

Instead of having to define objects that implement `__aiter__` and `__anext__` you create an asynchronous generator that does this seemingly by magic. This mirrors what generators did for the iterator protocol; instead of implementing `__iter__` and `__next__` for an object, you can just create a generator.

This is nicely stated in the rational of PEP 525 which also includes a nice example that shows the savings you make in code written when you use async generators.

In addition to code length savings, async generators also perform much better:

> Performance is an additional point for this proposal: in our testing of the reference implementation, asynchronous generators are 2x faster than an equivalent implemented as an asynchronous iterator.

---

Just to add some terminology here because it's getting difficult to keep track of terms sometimes:

- Generators: `def` functions that contain one or more `yield` expressions.
- Generator-based coroutine: A generator (`def` + `yield`) that is wrapped by [`types.coroutine`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.coroutine). You need to wrap it in `types.coroutine` if you need it to be considered a coroutine object.
- Asynchronous Generator: `async def` functions that contain a one or more `yield` expressions. These can also contain `await` expressions.
- Coroutine: `async def` without zero or more `await`s and no `yield`s.

Comment: Thanks. In "Asynchronous Generator: async def functions that contain a yield expression",  do you mean `await` instead of `yield`?

Comment: @Tim no no, if you only have an `await` in an `async def` you get a coroutine. The presence of `yield` in an `async def` is what makes it an asynchronous generator :-).

Comment: What is the difference between "Asynchronous Generator", Generator-based coroutine, and generators, in terms of their purposes? (not just in terms of how they are defined which you have described)

Comment: @Tim Generators are used as data producers (they *yield values*). Generator-based coroutines are used as consumers (you `.send` values to them or to a sub-generator they `yield from`). Asynchronous generators are asynchronous data producers (while coroutines are asynchronous data consumers).

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering about some questions regarding producer and consumer in your last comment, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46822070/why-are-generator-based-coroutines-consumes-asynchronous-generators-asynchronou?noredirect=1&lq=1. I was also wondering  about some question regarding  the terminology "generator-based coroutine" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46830144/are-these-two-kinds-of-generator-based-coroutines-the-same-concept?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: "without zero or more" is confusing wording, does it mean that it has to have zero yields and zero awaits?