# Are these two kinds of generator-based coroutines the same concept?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, generator, coroutine

There seem to be two kinds of generator-based coroutine:

1. From [a
   reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46203922/156458)
   by Jim Fasarakis Hilliard:

   > **Generator-based coroutine**: A generator (`def` + `yield`) that is wrapped by  [`types.coroutine`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.coroutine) . You need to wrap it in
   >   `types.coroutine` if you need it to be considered a coroutine object.
2. From Python in a Nutshell, which doesn't explicitly call it
   "generator-based coroutine":

   > When you write Python code based on  `asyncio`  (ideally also using
   >   add-on modules from  asyncio.org),  you’ll  usually  be  writing 
   >   coroutine  functions.  Up  to  Python  3.4 included, such functions
   >   are generators using the  `yield from`  statement covered in “yield
   >   from (v3-only)” on page 95, decorated with  `@asyncio.coroutine` ,
   >   covered in “asyncio coroutines” on page 518;

   From
   https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#differences-from-generators

   > generator-based coroutines (for asyncio code must be decorated with @asyncio.coroutine)

   http://masnun.com/2015/11/13/python-generators-coroutines-native-coroutines-and-async-await.html
   also calls it "generator-based coroutine".

Are the two kinds of generator-based coroutines the same concept?

If not, what are their differences in purposes and usages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're the same kind of coroutine. `types.coroutine` and `asyncio.coroutine` are just two separate ways to create them.

`asyncio.coroutine` is older, predating the introduction of `async` coroutines, and its functionality has shifted somewhat from its original behavior now that `async` coroutines exist.

`asyncio.coroutine` and `types.coroutine` have subtly different behavior, especially if applied to anything other than a generator function, or if asyncio is in [debug mode](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG).

Answer (score 3):

As far as I’m concerned, `async def` is the **proper** way to define a coroutine. `yield` and `yield from` have their purpose in generators, and they are also used to implement “futures”, which are the low-level mechanism that handles switching between different coroutine contexts.

I did [this diagram](https://default-cube.deviantart.com/art/Van-Rossum-s-Triangle-679791228) a few months ago to summarize the relationships between them. But frankly, you can safely ignore the whole business. Event loops have the job of handling all the low-level details of managing the execution of coroutines, so use one of those, like [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html). There are also `asyncio`-compatible wrappers for other event loops, like my own [`glibcoro`](https://github.com/ldo/glibcoro) for GLib/GTK.

In other words, stick to the `asyncio` API, and you can write “event-loop-agnostic” coroutines!