# Asynchronous generator functions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, generator

Consider [this example](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) from the Python documentation:

```
def gen(): # defines a generator function
  yield 123


async def agen(): # defines an asynchronous generator function
  yield 123
```

I know this example is simple, but what are things that I **can** do with `gen` and **not** with `agen`, and viceversa? In what way would I notice their difference?

#### Related:

I thought this question would help, but I I still don't get it:
[What are the differences between the purposes of generator functions and asynchronous generator functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46203876/what-are-the-differences-between-the-purposes-of-generator-functions-and-asynchr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one fits into the async/await framework and the other doesn't.

first, regular generator func. no cooperative multitasking here:

```
def f():
    return 4


def g():
    return 5


def gen():
    """cannot call async functions here"""
    yield f()
    yield g()


def run():
    for v in gen():
        print(v)
```

vs the below, *with* cooperative multitasking. allows other tasks to run between after `await`/during `async for`

```
async def f():
    return 4


async def g():
    return 5


async def gen():
    """can await async functions here"""
    yield await f()
    yield await g()


async def run():
    async for v in gen():
        print(v)


asyncio.run(run())
```

Comment: Thanks! QQ: Why I cannot call async functions in the first case but I can in the second case? Is that because only async functions can call async functions?

Comment: yep, that's right! in the first case you're not executing in the context of an event loop, so you can't "await" (i.e. uhh, pass control back to the event loop).